# Rails: How to destroy element of list with JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have short code on one view like this

```
ul#numbers
  li
  = phone_numbers
  button data-url=phone_number_path(phone_number) data-method=:delete data-remote=true Delete
```

(This is Slim) And this is work fine on serverside (destroy element from database).
And I have another view callled destroy.js.slim.
I need a code that destroy element (from page without page reload) but I dont know how to do that because li don`t have id (I think I need to use 'documentGetElementById' or something like this). Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Everything can have an ID : li#your-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you have action in controller like this:

```
def remove_phone_number
 @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_by(number: params[:phone_number])
 @phone_number.remove
end
```

And in your view:

```
<li data-phone-id="<%= phone_number.id %>">...</li>
```

You can create **remove_phone_number.js.erb** (the same name as controller action, by default) in view folder for this controller (e.g. **views/phones** ):

```
$('[data-phone-id=<%= @phone_number.id %>]').remove();
```

Note, that this code is just prototype, not testing, but presenting the idea.